# Lucene (or other alternatives) for boosting results based on the value of a field

Tags: lucene

Is their any non-hacky ways of applying boosting in Lucene on a per value basis, (as opposed to per field or per document)?

Basically, I would know ahead of time the "boost" of a value in multivalue field for each specific document, and I would store that boost value in the lucene index somehow.

If not, what are some possible alternatives or extensions to Lucene? that would allow this.

**Example:**

Document1: keywordFields with boost value = {apple, 10}, {pear, 50}

Document2: keywordFields with boost value = {apple, 15}

Document3: keywordFields with boost value = {apple, 20}, {pear, 10}

**Required search results (in required order)**

(1) Search on keyword field with **apple** value --> Document3, Document2, Document1

(2) Search on keyword field with **pear** value --> Document1, Document3

Comment: Are these values each contained in a discrete field, or do you want to give different boost values to terms within the same field.  In the first case, simply boost the field by the appropriate amount at index time.  In the second case, you'll need to look into payloads (See [Lucene payload scoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493249/lucene-payload-scoring))

Comment: Different boost values to terms within the same field. Seems like payload is something I need to investigate.