# How to add a different scores for each term using payload

Tags: java, lucene, payload

I created two classes, but I do not know how to do the payload of my function which calculates the score of each terms.I don't know if i must create author classes , please someone can help me. 
The first classe is:

```
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;
    import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;



         public class BoostingSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {
                public float scorePayload(int docID, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
                    float pload = 1.0f;
                    if (payload != null) {
                        pload = PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes);
                    }
                    System.out.println("===>  docid: " + docID + " payload: " + pload);
                    return pload;
               }}
```

The seconde classe is:
I added my idflocal function as follows, But I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right    :

```
           import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PayloadAttribute;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
            import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
            import  static Package.FonctionIDFlocal.idflocal;


            public class BulletinPayloadsFilter extends TokenFilter { 

            private PayloadAttribute attr;

            BulletinPayloadsFilter(TokenStream in,float idflocal) {
                super(in);
                attr = addAttribute(PayloadAttribute.class);
              }

              public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
                if (input.incrementToken()) {
                  BytesRef p =new BytesRef(PayloadHelper.encodeFloat(idflocal));;
                  attr.setPayload(p);
                } else {
                  attr.setPayload(null);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying? It looks like some custom scoring mechanism that scores documents according to a float value in the payload.

Comment: Yes that's it, my goal is to add scores to each term ,And the score I already calculated by another function.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document and the expected score (and calculation of that score) of that document?
Boosting is a multiplication factor on the original score.

Comment: But the problem is that I do not know where I must  add it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493249/lucene-payload-scoring?rq=1 maybe this post will help

Comment: Thank you @jvwilge